# rails: sorting User ages into ranges

Tags: ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this function

```
@users_age = User.group("date_trunc('year', age(dob))").count
```

which returns a hash of these entries that look like:

```
{
   "00:00:00" => 3,
   "1 year" => 5,
   "2 years" => 8,
   ...
}
```

(these are the number of user versus the count of users within those years)
I want to sort the years into ranges like [below 10 years, btn 10-19, btn 20-29, ...] to make the data more improved since I want to plot it in a chart.

How can I sort the entries?

---

**Update:**

I want the sorted entries to be returned as an hash like the example below. where the second is the number of users with their ages between that range.

```
{"above 50" => 89, "40-49" => 17, ...,"below 10" => 10}
```

Comment: I still don't understand where `00:00:00` is coming from, or where it goes in your expected output...

Comment: hmm, those are users who haven't set their ages

Comment: Ben, note that in your update you said you wanted the sorted entries to be return as a hash, but your example is an array of arrays.  If you want a hash, which I think makes sense, write it like this: `{"above 50" => 89, "40-49" => 17, ...,"below 10" => 10}`. Also, if the numbers in this hash (89, for example) are obtained by summing applicable values in the input hash, you should make that clear.

Comment: @cary, thanks. I have corrected

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
counts = your_hash.values.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |collection, value|
  collection[value/10] +=1
  collection
end
```

Comment: I'm not dealing with that 00:00:00.  I'd probably replace that first.